# How to get previous table cell value inside cell's updateItem method in JavaFx?

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8, tablecell

I want to have a `TableCell` with a custom `graphic` that animates on value change, where the animation type depends on the nature of the change, so I need to know the previous value to compare to the current one.

Here's your typical custom table cell (Kotlin code):

```
class MyTableCell<S, T> : TableCell<S, T>() {

    override fun updateItem(item: T?, empty: Boolean) {
        if (empty || field == null) {
            text = null
            graphic = null
        } else {
            // need to get the old value here
        }
    }
```

I see that the super method in `javafx/scene/control/TableCell.java` does know the old value and uses it compare it to the current one, but the override only gets the `newValue`:

```
private void updateItem(int oldIndex) {
    ...
    final T oldValue = getItem();
    ...
    final T newValue = currentObservableValue == null ? null : currentObservableValue.getValue();
    ...
    if (oldIndex == index) {
        if (!isItemChanged(oldValue, newValue)) {
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    updateItem(newValue, false); // sadly, `oldValue` is not passed
```

I can only think of an ugly workaround, so I wonder if there is some idiomatic way to get the old cell value?

Here is a sample app:

```
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty
import javafx.collections.FXCollections
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.*
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory
import javafx.stage.Stage
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.launch
import tornadofx.*

class Foo {
    val barProperty = SimpleDoubleProperty()
    var bar: Double
        get() = barProperty.get()
        set(value) = barProperty.set(value)
}


class FooApp: Application() {
    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
        val foos = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            Foo().apply { bar = 42.0 }
        )

        val table = TableView<Foo>(foos)

        val barColumn = TableColumn<Foo, Double>("Bar")
        barColumn.cellValueFactory = PropertyValueFactory<Foo, Double>("bar")
        barColumn.setCellFactory {
            FooTableCell<Foo, Double> { "%.2f".format(it) }
        }

        table.columns.add(barColumn)

        val scene = Scene(table, 400.0, 200.0)
        primaryStage.scene = scene
        primaryStage.title = "Table Cell"
        primaryStage.show()

        launch {
            while (isActive) {
                delay(500)
                val oldFoo = foos[0]
                // Replacing the old Foo instance with a new one,
                // updating the value of the `bar` field:
                foos[0] = Foo().apply {
                    bar = oldFoo.bar - 1.0 + Math.random() * 2.0
                }
                // because a change to a field cannot be detected by an observable list
                // and so does not propagates to the table. This won't result in
                // a visible change:
                // foos[0].bar = foos[0].bar - 1.0 + Math.random() * 2.0
            }
        }
    }
}

class FooTableCell<S, T>(private val format: (T) -> String) : TableCell<S, T>() {

    init {
        contentDisplay = ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY

        itemProperty().addListener(ChangeListener { obs, oldItem, newItem ->
            if (newItem != null && oldItem != null && newItem != oldItem) {
                // This is never true.
                println("!!! Old: $oldItem, New: $newItem")
            } else {
                println("Change listener:\nOld: $oldItem, New: $newItem\n")
            }
        })
    }

    override fun updateItem(item: T?, empty: Boolean) {
        val oldItem = this.item
        super.updateItem(item, empty)

        if (item != null && oldItem != null && item != oldItem) {
            // This is never true.
            println("!!! Old: $oldItem, New: $item")
        } else {
            println("updateItem:\nOld: $oldItem, New: $item\n")
        }

        if (empty || item == null) {
            graphic = null
            text = null
        } else if (tableRow != null) {
            val cell = this
            graphic = Label().apply {
                textProperty().bindBidirectional(cell.textProperty())
            }
            text = format(item)
        }
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Application.launch(FooApp::class.java, *args)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual value of the `item` property is changed by the default implementation of the `updateItem()` method, so just get the value before calling the default implementation:

```
public class MyTableCell<S,T> extends TableCell<S,T> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        T oldItem = getItem();
        super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can just register a change listener with the `itemProperty()`:

```
public class MyTableCell<S,T> extends TableCell<S,T> {

    public MyTableCell() {
        itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
            // do animation here...
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        // other functionality here...
    }
}
```

Here is a SSCCE demonstrating both techniques:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableCellWithChange extends Application {

    public static class ChangeAwareCell<S,T> extends TableCell<S,T> {

        public ChangeAwareCell() {
            itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
                System.out.printf("In listener, value for %s changed from %s to %s%n", getTableRow().getItem(), oldItem, newItem);
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            T oldItem = getItem();
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(item.toString());
                System.out.printf("Change in %s from %s to %s %n", getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()), oldItem, item);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Item, String> itemCol = column("Item", Item::nameProperty);
        table.getColumns().add(itemCol);

        TableColumn<Item, Number> valueCol = column("Value", Item:: valueProperty);
        table.getColumns().add(valueCol);

        valueCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new ChangeAwareCell<>());

        TableColumn<Item, Void> changeCol = new TableColumn<>();
        changeCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new TableCell<>() {
            private Button incButton = new Button("^");
            private Button decButton = new Button("v");
            private HBox graphic = new HBox(2, incButton, decButton);
            {
                incButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                    Item item = getTableRow().getItem();
                    item.setValue(item.getValue()+1);
                });
                decButton.setOnAction(e -> {
                    Item item = getTableRow().getItem();
                    item.setValue(item.getValue()-1);
                });
            }
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Void item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(graphic);
                }
            }
        });
        table.getColumns().add(changeCol);

        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 20  ; i++) {
            table.getItems().add(new Item("Item "+i, rng.nextInt(100)));
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(table);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String text, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(text);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        col.setPrefWidth(150);
        return col ;
    }


    public static class Item {
        private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty value = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Item(String name, int value) {
            setName(name);
            setValue(value);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getName();
        }

        public final StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return this.name;
        }


        public final String getName() {
            return this.nameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setName(final String name) {
            this.nameProperty().set(name);
        }


        public final IntegerProperty valueProperty() {
            return this.value;
        }


        public final int getValue() {
            return this.valueProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setValue(final int value) {
            this.valueProperty().set(value);
        }



    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Of course, these items will also change, e.g. when the user scrolls around the table, or if the cells are reused in other ways; so this might not be exactly when you want. You might want to add a listener to the appropriate property in the model instead. The simplest way to do this is probably to store a reference to the actual property from the model in the cell, and update that reference when the cell is updated:

```
public static class ChangeAwareCell<S,T> extends TableCell<S,T> {

    private Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property ;
    private ObservableValue<T> lastObservableValue ;

    private ChangeListener<T> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> valueChanged(oldValue, newValue);

    public ChangeAwareCell(Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property) {
        this.property = property ;
    }

    private void valueChanged(T oldValue, T newValue) {
        System.out.printf("Value changed from %s to %s %n", oldValue, newValue);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (lastObservableValue != null) {
            lastObservableValue.removeListener(listener);
        }
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
        } else {
            lastObservableValue = property.apply(getTableRow().getItem());
            lastObservableValue.addListener(listener);
            setText(item.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And of course make the corresponding change:

```
valueCol.setCellFactory(tc -> new ChangeAwareCell<>(Item::valueProperty));
```

Comment: Thank you, but in both cases I get either `null` for the old item or identical non-null values for the old and new items.

Comment: @Vitaly In the second code block, you cannot possibly get identical values for the old and new values. Change listeners are never fired if the old value and new value are equal. You should expect null for the old value in some cases (e.g. the first time the cell's `updateItem()` method is invoked).

Comment: My bad, in case of change listener we indeed cannot get two identical items, what I get is `null, value` or `value, null` but never two values. In case of the `updateItem` I can get two identical values, including two nulls. But never different values. I have just created a minimal sample app that shows this and added it to the question.

Comment: @Vitaly I don't work with Kotlin, but it looks like your model class `Foo` is not implemented correctly: specifically there doesn't appear to be a `barProperty()` method. I'm not convinced your test code for changing the values works either; isn't it blocking the FX Application Thread (which could prevent the cells from updating until all changes are complete, which would mean none of the intermediate values (between null and the final value) are ever passed to the cell)? I added a SSCCE to the answer (in Java).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your observation regarding missing `barProperty()` method was spot on. Now I can mutate the property without creating a new instance and get both the old and new values.